# Jquery mobile t.split is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a website that gets content dynamically from a database and puts them in the HTML code, which should consist of JQuery Mobile pages so I can click a link and it will slide to the corresponding page.

I'm running JQuery 1.9.1 and JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 to get the slide effect to work, but it's giving me an error saying "t.split is not a function". It also shows a large "LOADING" text in the middle of the page without any javascript there.

Am I missing something?

Edit:
I've chosen to ignore this for now. Nobody is responding anymore and the problems are only getting worse.

Comment: need to show some more code to see what is wrong

Comment: @DevZer0 Those 2 lines were literally all the code, got both of them from the Jquery website aswell.

Comment: Your PHP can't have anything to do with it, since it doesn't contain any JavaScript. Generally for JavaScript problems, it's useless to post any server-side script. You need to post the relevant **rendered** code. Also: What jQuery Version are you using?

Comment: @RoToRa I'm running 1.4.4 due to me working in a previously developed "template". I might be running the wrong version of JQuery Mobile so I think it's compatibility issues, except I don't know what version of JMobile would run with 1.4.4.

Comment: Considering that `Deferred` wasn't introduced until 1.5, it's likely. What jQuery Mobile version are you using? What does the jQuery Mobile website say about which jQuery version it needs?

Comment: @RoToRa I was just told that I can upgrade the Jquery, due to the old one not being needed anymore. I"m now running Jquery 1.9.1 and Jquery Mobile 1.3.1. Now it's saying "t.split is not a function".

Comment: @RoToRa The website has an example where they use 1.9.1 combined with 1.3.1, but it doesn't say anything specific for as far as I could find.

Comment: I guess this one is solved now, isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the question by first running a simpler version with only the essentials for making a 2 page'd JQuery Mobile example. The problem was that using only numbers for an ID isn't accepted, and I was missing the JQuery Mobile CSS file which allowed for the transition that I was looking for.

I've applied those solutions to this project and it works.